# SQLITE VIEWS + TRIGGERS

Tags: sql, sqlite

Pretty new to database - tried searching google as to what I'm doing wrong and not having luck.

This is a simple example that doesn't show the reason I'm doing this, but I'm simplifying as much as possible. (My real view actually joins 4 tables together)

- I have 1 table named 'people' with columns: *person_id, first_name, last_name*
- I have 1 view named 'phone_book2' with the following SQL code: *SELECT person_id as pid, first_name as fn FROM people*
- I have 1 trigger with the following SQL code: *CREATE TRIGGER test INSTEAD OF UPDATE ON phone_book2 BEGIN UPDATE people SET first_name = new.fn where person_id = pid; END*

THEN I try to update with the following command: *update phone_book2 set fn = 'crazy test' where pid = 2*

I get the following error: **no such column: pid**

Am I using triggers for something they aren't  mean't for? I read that you could use them with VIEWS but could be wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must qualify `pid` with the keyword `NEW`:

```
CREATE TRIGGER test 
INSTEAD OF UPDATE ON phone_book2 
BEGIN 
  UPDATE people 
  SET first_name = NEW.fn 
  WHERE person_id = NEW.pid; 
END
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=037a6d061e802a63a2fad9a2ff0ca864).

Comment: Newbie mistake. Thank you so much!